# How to sum up all the values of last column in an unknown dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Data Science and I am working on a simple self project using Google Colab. I took a data from a `something.csv` file and the file's columns are encrypted with `####`, so I don't know the names of the columns. I want to sum up all the values of the last column of that .csv file.

Here is my attempt to solve it using pyspark

```
df = spark.read.csv('something.csv', header=True)
```

Now I want to sum up values in 'col' column. I searched other stackoverflow posts but didn't understand how to sum up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.agg(sum(<col_name>))` to get sum of all values of **`last column`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---+-------------+---+
#| id|         Name| va|
#+---+-------------+---+
#|  1|       'Gary'|  5|
#|  1|      'Danny'|  4|
#|  2|      'Kevin'|  3|
#|  2|'Christopher'|  2|
#+---+-------------+---+

#lastcolumn
last_col=df[df.columns[len(df.columns)-1]]

#get sum of last column
df.agg(sum(last_col)).show()
#or
df.agg(sum(*[df.columns[-1]])).show()
#+-------+
#|sum(va)|
#+-------+
#|     14|
#+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

expression = '+'.join(cols_list)

df = df.withColumn('col', expr(expression))
```